# getfeatures of kml layer

Tags: android, google-maps

I really need help here! i'm working with google maps API for android.

I want to get all the features of my layer, to get all their properties. I used the below code, in the asynch funcion of KML demo :

```
Iterable<'?' extends Feature> multimap= kmlLayer.getFeatures();

for(Feature s: multimap){
    Log.w("display", s.getProperty("name"));
}
```

but it doesn't work! not even the log has been displayed!

I tried that :

```
Log.w("display", kmlLayer.getFeatures().toString();
```

I got: `[]` which means getfeatures is empty! any suggestions! pleaaase!

**PS :**

declaration of getfeatures:

```
public Iterable<? extends Feature> getFeatures(){
    return mRenderer.getFeatures();
}
```

declaration of getFeatures in the Renderer Class:

```
public Set<Feature> getFeatures() {
    return mFeatures.keySet();
}
```

Comment: I deleted my answer. You were right I was thinking of GeoJson. By the way, you should consider using GeoJson instead of KML, it seems to be better integrated than the KML format. For now...

Comment: Pleaaase some one help me ! i tried to display kmlLayer.getFeatures() i got : [] !! the setOnFeatureClickListener worked!! I don't get it!